# how to check if an attribute <Reporting_date> YYYYMMDD </Reporting_Date> in a .xml file is equal to a fixed Date value

Tags: python, linux, xml, shell

I am new to python and wondering how to solve below use-case using python script in the shell script.

I have a shell script which holds variables as file name, ODATE value which is fixed in the format YYYYMMDD. It does some checks on file name.
In the next step I want to run a python script which actually checks the attribute <Reporting_date> YYYYMMDD </Reporting_Date> value for every occurrence in the test.xml file is equal to a fixed value from ODATE.

- If all the values for <Reporting_date> YYYYMMDD </Reporting_Date> are matching the ODATE then print message "all the attributes are matched".
- If we find one mismatch while scanning multiple records in test.xml file, on the 1st mismatch  itself stop scanning the entire test.xml file, and print message "Encountered a mismatch"

Could anyone of you please guide me with this use-case. It would be much helpful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code example what you have done this far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this (I haven't test this code and I don't know structure of your XML file, but you should get an idea).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ODATE = '20210215' 
allok = True
for child in root.iter('Reporting_date'):
    if child.text != ODATE:
        allok = False
        print ("Encountered a mismatch")
        break
if allok:
   print("All attributes are matched")
```

For more information see https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

--- EDIT using findall instead of iter (see comments) ---

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ODATE = '20210215' 
allok = True
for directchild in root:
    for child in directchild.findall("REPORTING_DATE"):
        # this supports multiple reporting_date in one POSITION structure.
        # If you know that there always is only one, find would be better.
        if child.text != ODATE:
            allok = False
            print ("Encountered a mismatch")
            break
if allok:
   print("All attributes are matched")
```

Comment: My .xml file is having below structure:                                                               ```<POSITIONS>
  <POSITION>
    <ISIN>aaaaaaa</ISIN>
    <ACCOUNT>7777777</ACCOUNT>
    <POSITION>11111</POSITION>
    <SETTLEMENT_DATE>20210202</SETTLEMENT_DATE>
    <REPORTING_DATE>20210202</REPORTING_DATE>
  </POSITION>
  <POSITION>
    <ISIN>bbbbbbb</ISIN>
    <ACCOUNT>66666666</ACCOUNT>
    <POSITION>888888888</POSITION>
    <SETTLEMENT_DATE>20210203</SETTLEMENT_DATE>
    <REPORTING_DATE>20210202</REPORTING_DATE>
  </POSITION>
</POSITIONS> ```

Comment: Hi @ex4,  I tried your script, but for both positive and negative scenario its giving All attributes are matched. Does the code work for the above structure given in the commnet, should I alter anywhere?

Comment: I updated my example a bit. Now it uses `iter` -method which loops certain tag in all levels. And make sure your ODATE is string, not int.

Comment: I got the below error:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xml_file_date_tag_check.py", line 13, in <module>
    for child in root.iter('REPORTING_DATE'):
AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'

Comment: Hence instead of "iter" I used "findall" and for both positive and negative scenario its giving All attributes are matched.

Comment: Documention says: "Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. " Your root elements direct children are named `POSITION`.  So using that you'd need do nested loops. According to documentation I linked to my answer,  there should be `iter` method available though. Interesting.

Comment: Hi @ex4, I tried using "getiterator" instead of "iter" and it worked now! :) Many thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Ok, You probably have Python2 and it has a bit different methods. Nice that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<POSITIONS>
   <POSITION>
      <ISIN>aaaaaaa</ISIN>
      <ACCOUNT>7777777</ACCOUNT>
      <POSITION>11111</POSITION>
      <SETTLEMENT_DATE>20210202</SETTLEMENT_DATE>
      <REPORTING_DATE>20210202</REPORTING_DATE>
   </POSITION>
   <POSITION>
      <ISIN>bbbbbbb</ISIN>
      <ACCOUNT>66666666</ACCOUNT>
      <POSITION>888888888</POSITION>
      <SETTLEMENT_DATE>20210203</SETTLEMENT_DATE>
      <REPORTING_DATE>20210215</REPORTING_DATE>
   </POSITION>
</POSITIONS>'''
ODATE = '20210215'
root = ET.fromstring(XML)
dates = root.findall('.//REPORTING_DATE')
for date in dates:
    if date.text == ODATE:
        print(f'ODATE {ODATE} and REPORTING_DATE {date.text} are the same dates')
    else:
        print(f'ODATE {ODATE} and REPORTING_DATE {date.text} are NOT the same dates')
```